# how to safely remove granite counter top

Tags: kitchen-counters, granite

is it possible to re-use granite countertop when i am replacing cabinets in my kitchen? or is there a high chance of breaking it?

Thanks

Comment: I'd recommend getting a labor estimate from a local granite installer.  THey'll know how to separate the top from the cabinets safely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible & common. Cut any caulking clean through with a knife & slide it free, never pry up to free it. For solid sections you can just move those around carefully as-is. For sections that have a sink or cooktop cut-out, you'll want to sandwich the front edge by clamps or screws with 2x4's or wider. Slide the front edge out enough to sandwich that in place, then you can tip it up & move it to another room where you'll store it tipped up & not flat.

Comment: Possible and common, but still with a high chance of failure, especially around the sink. The adhesive used will have an impact on your success. It also varies widely with the type of stone. Have a backup $$ fund in the budget.

Comment: If you have any difficulties removing it, it would be more cost effective to have a professional countertop installer remove it for you. It would be much cheaper than having to replace the entire thing since you probably would not be able to match it up perfectly with a new piece if it broke. They have specialty tools which can brace the weak parts i.e. the sink cutouts when it is removed. They can also reinstall the countertop when you get your new cabinets, and make any adjustments necessary for a professional looking installation.